# Is there a way to condense this into an SQL table?

Tags: sql, create-table

So I'm trying to create a database for some existing raw data and I'm pretty new to this and was going to create a table the long way. This is the data I have:

[Raw Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHTlM.png)

The table reads like x,y and gives a value so if it is 0 and 727, the value should be 19.2. I was going to create a table with 3 columns: x, y and value. But this means having to add 55 rows of data, so I was just wondering if there is a work around for this? It might be something very obvious that I'm just missing

Comment: Not sure what *create a table the long way* means but X, Y, Value is the correct normalised data, 55 rows is nothing.

Comment: A `x, y, value` approach is how it's normally done in a database. Later you can pivot such data to a spreadsheet form. But DDL statements (like the creation of a table) can differ between database types.

Comment: Your table has 55 cells and your database table represents those with 55 rows. I don't see a problem

Answer (score 0):

By creating a table representing your values with each unique `X-Y-Value` as a row you are creating the most compact and best utilised table, the values being stored including the lookups exactly match your tabular layout.

You are only storing the values you need, there is no duplication and the data would be what's considered as normalised.

A clustered index on `X,Y` will provide for index seeks directly to the required value, however this would be a true benefit for row counts in the 1000s+, with just a handful of rows typically the entire table would be cached after a single read - depending on the database engine being used.